# How would I open a file through user input?

Tags: python-3.x

This is what I'vre tried so far:

```
print('''You will have to enter a file name
Once the file name has been entered, the program will then print out your ASCII art''')
file_name = input('Enter file name: ')
with open(file_name) as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        for x in f:
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

one for loop should be removed from your code as commented and you should print line.

```
print('''You will have to enter a file name
Once the file name has been entered, the program will then print out your ASCII art''')
file_name = input('Enter file name: ')
with open(file_name) as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        #for x in f:
        print(line)
```